# How to generate cert7.db from cert9. with certutil

Tags: ssl, debian, ssl-certificate, certutil

due to a legacy project I need to generate a cert7.db file in order to use with LDAP. I've downloaded certutil on Debian but by default it generates cert9.db.

There is a way to convert cert9.db to cert7.db?

Thanks